# How to check via command line if a VirtualBox VM is not running on Windows

Tags: windows, jenkins, virtualbox

I am working on a Jenkins project to remotely startup and shutdown a specific VM with user-supplied parameters.

I have managed to find a way to determine that the specified VM is started up and running and ready for further instructions, but I have yet to find a way to determine that the specified VM has powered off.

The current code used in the build step is this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

ECHO Shutting down VM %VM% on Host %computername%...
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" controlvm %VM% acpipowerbutton
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 EXIT /B 1

:LOOP
WAITFOR /T 10 VMtoShutDown 2>NUL
FOR /f %%a IN ('VBoxManage list runningvms ^| FINDSTR %VM%') DO SET VM_State=%%a
IF [!VM_State!] EQU [] (
ECHO %VM% is not running.
EXIT /b 0
)
GOTO LOOP
```

The logic is this:

1. Send `controlvm` command to perform ACPI shutdown of target VM.
2. Use `FOR` to iterate through a list of Running VMs to see if target VM is still running.
3. If target VM is still running, don't do anything, and go back to the beginning of :LOOP and re-check until result changes.
4. If target VM is no longer seen in the list of Running VMs, consider this build step a success.

The main problem is the `FOR` statement in the `:LOOP` clause. In the Startup portion of the build step, I can use `VboxManage list runningvms` to determine if the specified VM is listed, and thus process it as such and indicate that the Jenkins build to startup the specified VM is successful.

However, I noticed that once the target VM is taken off the list of running VMs by way of the earlier `controlvm` command, the entire `DO` part of the `FOR` statement simply doesn't do anything. It doesn't set the `VM_State=%%a`, for one, and it doesn't do anything else I had thrown into the `FOR` statement. This causes the `:LOOP` to keep looping infinitely as the only condition checker doesn't fire.

**Question: Is there any way to determine if a VM of a particular name is powered off?**

Notes:

- The VirtualBox plugin for Jenkins is incompatible with the current VirtualBox version (5.1.30).
- The Jenkins version is 2.122.
- The code above is tested to behave the same when running as a standalone .bat file on the target machine and on my own machine.
- All systems involved are on Windows 10 v1803.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on Windows 10, hope it helps!

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

ECHO Shutting down VM %VM% on Host %computername%...
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" controlvm %VM% acpipowerbutton
ECHO VirtualBox command return code: %ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 EXIT /B 1

:LOOP
REM Sleep for 1 second by using a ping hack :)
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" showvminfo %VM% | findstr /c:"powered off" >NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO END
echo VM %VM% not powered off yet...
GOTO LOOP

:END
echo VM %VM% powered off.
```